Usage of MudCarousel SelectedIndex property
I would set SelectedIndex pf MudCarousel to the last item when page displayed in the first time but it always display the first item or it doesen't work as the example shows: example
I tried using the MoveTo(_source.Count - 1) method, but the carousel still doesn't load when the page is opened.

You can set the value of the SelectedIndex in OnInitialized
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    selectedIndex = _source.Count() - 1;
}

MudBlazor snippet

Hi, Uerschel! Thanx for help. Not this was the solution but it helped me to think over it. I put a pager below the carousel and I set its Selected property with SelectedPage but SelectedIndex was the good for it.

Glad to hear. If you found a solution to your own problem you can post it as answer and select it as such. I'm sure it will help others with similar problems.
